# Can't Write Configuration File

Tags: aptana, configuration-files, aptana3

I have been unsuccessful in getting Aptana 3.0.8 to start. I keep getting the error

```
The configuration area at 'C:\Users\Devon\.eclipse\com.aptana.rcp.product_3.0.8.201201201658_68819209\configuration' is not writable. Please choose a writable location using the '-configuration' command line option.
```

I have used the `-configuration` command within the target area of my shortcut to point to two different locations at two different times.

First I made a folder in the root of my drive and made sure that it was writable, but still got the same error, except it would say that the folder I specified was not writable instead of listing the folder in the above error.

I also tried to point it to write to a mapped network drive via my server and it still gave me the same error.

I have read other posts on this site and none of the resolutions solved my issue. I also went into my local appdata folder and changed the path of the default workspace location within the config.ini folder and changed it to a directory that does not have spaces in its name in hopes that would resolve the issue.

I really needed to work on my business website and thus have installed Aptana 2 in the mean time because that seems to be working without any issues. However I would really like to be able to get Aptana 3 working.

I am running Windows 7 Pro x64

Thanks in advance for any help provided here

Comment: Where did you install Aptana Studio 3?

Comment: I installed Aptana Studio 3 to my local appdata folder. Should i change where it is installed? I will try and see what happens.

Comment: odd, installing it to my Program Files folder resolved the issue. Thanks for the assistance. This problem is now resolved.